# Как зайти на страницу RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, python, rabbitmq

Установил `RabbitMQ`. Проверил - все работает. Сообщения отправляются и принимаются. Но вот не могу зайти на страницу сервера `RabbitMQ`. Ввожу в браузер `http://0.0.0.0:15672/` и ничего. Браузер говорит, что такой страницы не существует. ЧТо я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

По умолчанию, веб-интерфейс отключен, но его можно включить командой на *nix системах:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

На Windows включается командой из папки sbin, где установлен сервер:

```
rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
```

После чего необходимо перезапустить RabbitMQ и войти через браузер на http://localhost:15672. По умолчанию, логин и пароль для входа в RabbitMQ Managment Plugin: guest/guest

С версии 3.3 было введено ограничение на доступ по guest/guest с хоста отличного от localhost. Но вы можете создать пользователя test c паролем test и зайти под ним с любого хоста:

```
rabbitmqctl add_user test test \n
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test administrator 
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

Comment: А почему, если попытаться зайти с другой машины под `guest/guest`, то `Login failed` ?

Comment: Обновил ответ :)

Answer (score 4):

```
http://127.0.0.1:15672/
```

или

```
http://localhost:15672/
```

Если RabbitMQ стоит на другой машине, то соответственно нужно указать адрес машины

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас windows и вы хотите стартануть rabbitmq через docker в среде разработки intellj idea, вот как сделал я используя совет Firepro, описанный выше.

файл `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
#docker-compose up
version: "3.9"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    container_name: localhost_rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "guest"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "guest"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
```

Мы его стартуем и получаем контейнер. Нажимаем в докере по названию контейнера, в данном случае это `localhost_rabbitmq`. Переходим во вкладку terminal и вставляем команду `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`. Всё!!!